# MySQL: show strings in result that were not found

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL db table with a column containing strings. And I have a list of strings. Some of the strings from the list can be found in my table, others can't. See my table TableName:

```
<TableName>
IntegerColumn, StringColumn
1, one
2, two
3, three
4, four
```

If I execute the query

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE StringColumn NOT IN ('three', 'four', 'five', 'six');
```

I get a result of two rows, which contain nothing but NULL.
How can I see for which of the strings there was **no** match? Because I want to add them to the db table

Thx in advance

Comment: unclear. explain properly.

Comment: what is `list of strings` here?

Comment: list of strings is 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'.

Comment: also edited the explanation, hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is, 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six' if any of this string is not present in the database you want to identify that.

Using query I think it will be tough. You can just use below query to get the available strings and the counts. Then, if you are using a programming language you can identify which string are not present in the result and then proceed further.

```
SELECT StringColumn, count(*) FROM TableName group by StringColumn
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: marked this as answer. and using a programming language is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following sample

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table 
    (
 id int auto_increment primary key,  
 details varchar(30)
 );

INSERT INTO sample_table
(id, details)
VALUES
(1, 'One'),
(2, 'Two'),
(3, 'Three'),
(4, 'Four'),
(5, 'Five');
```

I ran the query

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table
WHERE details NOT IN ('two', 'three', 'nine');
```

which gave the correct output of:

```
1 One 
4 Four 
5 Five
```

If you've got NULL returned then there is something you're not explaining in your question.  Can you provide schema information or even a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and I'm sure you'll get a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should not go this way. Check the following demo to ensure that your code is correct. Now what really matters is the set of data present in the table.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c8339/3)**

Here is the DDL:

```
create table tab1 (IntegerColumn int(2), StringColumn varchar(20));
insert into tab1 values(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four');
```